# How to increase the request header size limit Haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

How to increase the header size limit in haproxy, currently the default settings allowed only 8KB.

Due to this we are facing 400 error at client side.
localhost haproxy[21502]: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx [xx/xxx/xxxx:xx:xx:xx.xx] www-http www-http/ -1/-1/-1/-1/0 400 187 - - PR-- 411/23/0/0/0 0/0 ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [tune.maxrewrite](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.3/configuration.html#tune.maxrewrite) to a higher value.
It is strongly recommended that the header should be lower then the 8KB.

Here a link which shows the header limits on different servers [Maximum HTTP request header size defaults compared across web servers](https://www.geekersdigest.com/max-http-request-header-size-server-comparison/)